# Moovit Deep Linking Fails,Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift3

did anyone successfully deep linked from his app to a directions to a place in moovit ? why can't i ?! it just opens the app and does nothing ....
if anyone successfully deep linked to a direction to anywhere please help.

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "moovit://")!) {
            // Moovit installed - launch app (with parameters)
            let MoovitURL: String = "moovit://directions?dest_lat=40.758896&dest_lon=-73.985130&dest_name=TimesSquare&orig_lat=40.735845&orig_lon=-73.990512&orig_name=UnionSquare&auto_run=true&partner_id=<testApp2345>"

            let escapedString = MoovitURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: escapedString!)!)
        }else {
            // Moovit not installed - send to store
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id498477945")!)

        }
    }
```

even Moovit's own example isn't working for me....Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the .urlHostAllowed parameter.
Using the .urlQueryAllowed parameter instead will only convert the parameters after '?'.

Fixed your code:

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "moovit://")!) {
         // Moovit installed - launch app (with parameters)
        let MoovitURL: String = "moovit://directions?dest_lat=40.758896&dest_lon=-73.985130&dest_name=TimesSquare&orig_lat=40.735845&orig_lon=-73.990512&orig_name=UnionSquare&auto_run=true&partner_id=<testApp2345>"

        let escapedString = MoovitURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: escapedString!)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }else {
        // Moovit not installed - send to store
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id498477945")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Thank a lot man! I appreciate your efforts to help . I will check if the code works and make sure to mark the answer correct if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening this url in Safari and see if it works (It does for me).
Looks like the problem is with the code, maybe try without addingPercentEncoding or use the new openURL API

Comment: Can you give a code example maybe?that will be so helpful.

Comment: You can use the same url as in the example, Just copy and paste it in Safari. Also, make sure your Moovit app is configured to same metro area as the locations you're trying to open (In the exmple it's in NYC)

Comment: Dude i tried anything and it doesn't work can you help me change the code so it it will work please? I'm so desperate :(

Comment: without addingPercentEncoding i get a crash cause the string doesn't count as a URL ...